# How does `shutdown -k` disable logins?

Tags: shutdown, pam, upstart

This is the `-k` option's documentation in [`man shutdown`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man8/shutdown.8.html) (at least on Ubuntu):

```
 -k   Only send out the warning messages and disable 
      logins, do not actually bring  the  system down.
```

I initially assumed that this will use `pam_nologin` to lock out logins. However, I tested it out and do not see `/etc/nologin` created after running `shutdown -k`.

1. How does `shutdown -k` disable logins?
2. How can you re-enable logins after a `shutdown -k`?

Comment: What OS are you seeing this on? I don't have it in my man page on Linux/Gentoo.

Comment: RHEL, Centos and Ubuntu. I believe it's the upstart version of shutdown.

Comment: Can you confirm that running `shutdown -k` actually disables logins? On Ubuntu 12.04 it had no effect other then printing the wall msg.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Usage from a Red Hat based distro

I believe the `-k` switch just fakes that the system is shutting down and so will print the wall message, but does little else.

```
   -k
       Don't halt, power-off, reboot, just write wall message.
```

To cancel a shutdown event:

```
$ sudo shutdown -c
```

#### Usage from Ubuntu

When I tried using the above on Ubuntu 12.04 I was able to do the following command:

```
$ sudo -i
$ strace -s 2000 -o sdown.log shutdown -k 23:00

Broadcast message from manny@manny
    (/dev/pts/1) at 20:25 ...

The system is going down for maintenance in 155 minutes!

$ shutdown -c
shutdown: Cannot find pid of running shutdown
```

Looking through the `strace` log file, `sdown.log` I saw nothing that would seem to indicate it had any effect at actually blocking logins from users.

```
$ grep open sdown.log
open("/etc/ld.so.cache", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
open("/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnih.so.1", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
open("/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnih-dbus.so.1", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
open("/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdbus-1.so.3", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
open("/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
open("/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librt.so.1", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
open("/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
open("/usr/lib/locale/locale-archive", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
open("/usr/share/locale/locale.alias", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
open("/usr/share/locale/en_US.UTF-8/LC_MESSAGES/upstart.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/share/locale/en_US.utf8/LC_MESSAGES/upstart.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/share/locale/en_US/LC_MESSAGES/upstart.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/share/locale/en.UTF-8/LC_MESSAGES/upstart.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/share/locale/en.utf8/LC_MESSAGES/upstart.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/share/locale/en/LC_MESSAGES/upstart.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/share/locale-langpack/en_US.UTF-8/LC_MESSAGES/upstart.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/share/locale-langpack/en_US.utf8/LC_MESSAGES/upstart.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/share/locale-langpack/en_US/LC_MESSAGES/upstart.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/share/locale-langpack/en.UTF-8/LC_MESSAGES/upstart.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/share/locale-langpack/en.utf8/LC_MESSAGES/upstart.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/share/locale-langpack/en/LC_MESSAGES/upstart.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/etc/localtime", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
open("/var/run/shutdown.pid", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
```

So I would be inclined to think that the man page is simply wrong in the way that it's phrasing that the `-k` switch will disable logins.

#### A bug in shutdown's source?

Per a comment left by @Gilles, he directed us to the source of `shutdown.c`, specifically from this URL: http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/admin/upstart. The `shutdown` utility is part of the Upstart package on Ubuntu & CentOS currently.

Looking through the source, `./util/shutdown.c` take note that the file used to control whether users are enabled/disabled from logging in is `/etc/nologin`, as you suspected. This file is only ever written to from the function `timer_callback()`. This function is then called as a callback by this timer:

```
  /* Call a timer every minute until we shutdown */
  NIH_MUST (nih_timer_add_periodic (NULL, 60,
            (NihTimerCb)timer_callback,
            message));
```

From within the `timer_callack()` function there's this block which would appear to write the `/etc/nologin` file when there's < 5 minutes left before shutting down:

```
  /* Write /etc/nologin with less than 5 minutes remaining */
  if (delay <= 5) {
    FILE *nologin;

    nologin = fopen (ETC_NOLOGIN, "w");
    if (nologin) {
      fputs (msg, nologin);
      fclose (nologin);
    }
  }
```

The switch, `-k` only sends the warning 1 time, and then exits.

```
  { 'k', NULL, N_("only send warnings, don't shutdown"),
    NULL, NULL, &warn_only, NULL },
```

Here it is exiting:

```
  if (warn_only)
    exit (0);
```

Comment: This doesn't even attempt to answer the question. It's clear that you're talking about a different implementation.

Comment: @Gilles - sorry I don't understand your comment. What am I missing here? The OP included RHEL/CentOS in the comment above and this is from the man page of one of those distros. CentOS 6 uses upstart.

Comment: Given that both the question and the answer list the documentation for `-k` and that the documentation is very different, it's clear that you're talking about different implementations. The question is how `shutdown -k` disables logins; citing documentation from an implementation where `-k` does not disable logins is not useful.

Comment: @Gilles - fair enough, but I've seen enough variance in man pages even when dealing with the same distros (differing versions of distros), so it's kinda of a weak data point.

Comment: @Gilles - included some of the output from `strace shutdown -k ...` I don't see it doing anything that would seem to indicate that it is disabling logins.

Comment: Looking at the source from Ubuntu 14.04, I confirm that this is a bug in the man page: the code doesn't do anything that would disable logins if invoked with `-k`, in particular it doesn't touch `/etc/nologin`.

Comment: That's unfortunate, I thought this switch could be useful when I need to lock user's out temporarily. Nice research looking into the source. Where did you consult the source? I keep meaning to get a URL so I can more quickly consult the source on Q's like this too.

Comment: Ubuntu package sources: `http://packages.ubuntu.com/PACKAGE-NAME` → pick a release → download the `.orig.tar.gz`, `.diff.gz` and `.dsc` files (or whatever is there). `dpkg-source` will unpack everything, if you have it.

Comment: @Giles thank you for confirming! Seems to be a bug in the documentation in RHEL6 as well. Can you submit the answer so I could mark it as so?

Comment: @BeamingMel-Bin - I spoke w/ Gilles in chat, he was OK with me just adding the source to my A instead of adding another A.